# how to scroll tableview on Page control in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I want to scroll tableview on Page control or when it is scrolled horizontally but when user is on 1st page i want to show 3 records then when user scroll for next page i want to show next 3 records & so on.
How to do this .currently i am not able to understand how should i show next 3 records when user scroll for next page?

Comment: Can you show us your View Controller object hierarchy & codes ?

Comment: `UIPageControl` has a property called `currentPage` that you can use to distinguish which data to collect.

Comment: currently i am reloading table view when user scrolls so it is showing me all records at a time but i want to show 3 record 1st then next records on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

below method will get called when you try to scroll the page(page control), so in this method set content offset of your table view.Just set Y axis .you can set any value in y axis, it is upto you. so whenever you try to scroll the page, the tableview will be automatically scrolled vertically.

```
   -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
  {
      int page=scr.contentOffset.x / scr.frame.size.width;
      [pageMap setCurrentPage:page];
      yourtableview.contentOffset=CGPointMake(0, 25);//you can set any value in y axis
  }
```

let me know it is working or not!!!

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: my table view is scrolling vertically but problem to is that i am not understanding how should i show 1st 3 records on 1st page & then remaining 3 as per scroll next pages

Comment: can i have screenshot of iphone simulator so i can understand it better way dear???

Answer (score 0):

[Scroll table view](http://code4app.net/ios/Tab-Viewer-ScrollView/4f84fff306f6e75044000002)

This code might help you.